# Roman numbering of pages on ToC, but arabic on document

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, roman

this could seem a little awkward, but apparently I need to do it this way.

I have a document (class `book`) that uses arabic page numbering starting from the introduction page. Before that I have the `\tableofcontents` where I would like to show the page numbers as Roman, even when the real ones are numbered as arabic.

Example of wanted ToC:

> 1. First chapter --- I
> 2. Second chapter  ---- X

But the real page number of the first chapter must be 1, second chapter must be 10, etc. I only need to transform the numbers to Roman on the ToC.

I've tried with this:

```
% ...
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \tableofcontents
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \chapter{First chapter} % Page: 1
    % ... 
    \chapter{Second chapter} % Page: 10
% ...
```

But that just changes the pages where the ToC is, not the ToC itself, and that's not what I want.

Comment: Could you post a minimal (non-)working example that we can play with?

Comment: What is the rationale behind this awkwardness? Which page number style should be used by `\pageref`?

Comment: `\pagenumbering{arabic}` should be preceded by `\cleardoublepage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically all sectioning commands write `\thepage` to the ToC using `\addcontentsline`. You can update `\addcontentsline` to

```
\renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{%
  \addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{\Roman{page}}}}
```

which writes `\Roman{page}` to the ToC instead of the default formatting `\thepage` (which may be different from `\Roman{page}`). A better option might be to patch `\addcontentsline` using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\addcontentsline}{\thepage}{\Roman{page}}{}{}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\addcontentsline}{\thepage}{\Roman{page}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{A chapter} % Page: 1
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}

\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{10}
\chapter{Another chapter} % Page: 10
\section{Another section}
\subsection{Another subsection}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think this makes sense.

Comment: @egreg: The OP mentioned "this could seem a little awkward, but apparently I need to do it this way."

Comment: I see; it doesn't make sense nonetheless. ;-)

Comment: No, it doesn't make any sense, but it's what I needed, thank you!!

I have faith that the person responsible for writing this nonsense rule at my university will be punished eventually... and very badly.

Comment: @Cataphractus: My suggestion using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) works with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), provided that the patch is performed *after* `\usepackage{hyperref}`.

Comment: @Cataphractus: Are you sure that you get the rule right? Maybe the pages on which the TOC is printed should be numbered roman?! That makes lot more sense and is quite common …

Comment: @Tobi Indeed it makes more sense and that's what I had previously. I suppose the rule could mean both things, but as my friend did his project using the "nonsense way" I also need to know how to do it, just in case.